# Find Transactions in Time Range, Ignoring Date

Tags: t-sql

My client wants to know all the people that logged in to the system during the night hours. I keep all login times. Basically looking for anyone who logged in from 1am-5am for all of this year. Is there a way to find this using SQL?

I keep my time in basic DateTime Format with a 24 hour clock.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the table structure? How do you cater for daylight saving time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will be fine using [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Assume the following columns exist, and assume dates and times don't test for daylight saving time.

This will select all the UserIDs from a table where the time is between 1am and 5pm, since January 1st.

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    LoginDate
FROM
    [dbo].[LoginDates]
WHERE
    [LoginDate] > '20160101'
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,[LoginDate]) >= 1
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,[LoginDate]) < 5
```

**Notes**:

- The `LoginDate > '20160101'` will check for all logins after midnight on the 1st of January 2016.
- I'm using `>=` and `<` instead of `BETWEEN`, because it's more accurate.